# Approximation of $\pi$ with $\tan(x/4) - \cot(x/4)$ and Newton`s method?

Tags: real-analysis

If I find the Null in $\tan(x/4) - \cot(x/4)$ I should get a good approximation for $\pi$.

So I have

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{\tan(x/4) - \cot(x/4)}{\tan(x/4)dx - \cot(x/4)dx}$$

I've done this once before, but never got the result that I wanted.

So I'm sure I have to do some shaping of the terms before - do you have any hint?

Comment: Shouldn't your denominator be the derivative of that numerator , that is $\frac{1}{4} \csc ^2\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{4} \sec ^2\left(\frac{x}{4}\right) = \csc ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$? Start with $x_0 = 5$, for example.

Comment: Note that $\tan(x/4) - \cot(x/4) = -2 \cot(x/2)$. Newton iteration becomes $x_{n+1} = x_n + \sin(x_n)$.

Comment: Tomorrow will be $\pi$ day !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $\pi \approx 3.15$ then?  :-)

Comment: In US notation, tomorrow will be $3/14/15$ and at $9$am ....

Comment: @WimC. Sorry, it is today !!! The $9$ is already lost except on the West coast. Cheers :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator is the derivative of the numerator, so the iteration formula should be:

$$\tag 1x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{\tan\left(\dfrac x4\right) - \cot\left(\dfrac x4\right)}{\dfrac{1}{4} \csc ^2\left(\dfrac{x}{4}\right)+\dfrac{1}{4} \sec ^2\left(\dfrac{x}{4}\right)} = x_n + \dfrac{2 \cot \left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{\csc ^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)} = x_n + \sin (x_n)$$

As noted in two comments, we could have done the trig simplification immediately, that is:

$$\tan\left(\dfrac x4\right) - \cot\left(\dfrac x4\right) = -2 \cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

This greatly simplifies finding the iteration formula as you end up with the RHS of $(1)$ immediately. I left the solution as is to point out where your issue occurred, but the trig simplification is definitely preferred.

One has to be careful with the selection of $x_0$ given the graph of $-2 \cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$:

[image]

If we start with $x_0 = 5$, we get a result of $3.1415926535897932385$ in five steps to $20-$digit accuracy.

Comment: I think the expression can be simplified: $$\tan{\left ( \frac{x}{4} \right )} - \cot{\left ( \frac{x}{4} \right )} = -2 \cot{ \left ( \frac{x}{2} \right )}$$

Comment: As noted in my comment the iteration itself can be simplified quite a bit.

Comment: @WimC: Both simplifications have been noted. Regards